# Lombok Annotations are not working with inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, annotations, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I have something like a parent class (`File A.java`).
Every class is extending this class, as every class needs `name`.

When I use in `File X.java` the `@With` function, it works for the `.withDescription("xxx")` which is part of `File B.java`.
But it's not possible to use `@With` function with `.withName("xxx");`
At least IntelliJ is not showing `.withName("xxx")`.
But the inherited `.setName("xxx")` is working as expected.

Any idea how to get this working as expected?
I have seen [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52344036/863403) to use the `@SuperBuilder`, but I wanted to do it without the `@Builer` / `@SuperBuilder`

File A.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@With
@MappedSuperclass
public class A {
  public String name;
}
```

File B.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@With
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class B extends A {
  public String description;
}
```

File X.java

```
public class X {
  public void x() {
    var b = new B().withDescription("xxx"); // it works
    b.withName("xxx"); // is NOT working.
    b.setName("xxx"); // only set is working, even it's only inherited.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `@AllArgsConstructor` to A

Comment: I thought I tried it, but it looks like I haven't.   but in A I also have:     `@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;` 
with @AllArgsConstructor I can also set withId, which I don't want to do, that's why I have `@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)`.  Any idea to awoid this Ramin?

Comment: Nothing comes to my mind, except Builder which you don't wanna use it.